# Using magrittr and which

Tags: r, magrittr

I want to rewrite the following code with pipes from magrittr:

```
max(diff(which(diff(runif(50)) > 0 )))
```

My straightforward approach would be:

```
library(magrittr)
runif(50) %>% diff > 0 %>% which %>% diff %>% max
```

But  this fails due to the (first) *which*:

```
runif(50) %>% diff > 0 %>% which
```

*Error in which(.) : argument to 'which' is not logical*

I am unsure why this error occurs and why piping to which seems to be different from piping to other functions as the output of "diff > 0" is a logical vector.

On a sidenote, would there be a way to pipe for the comparison, bluntly speaking

```
 runif(50) %>% diff %>% > 0
```

Comment: The fully magrittr'ed version would be `x %>% diff %>% is_greater_than(0) %>% which %>% diff %>% max` imo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
runif(50) %>% diff %>% `>`(0) %>% which %>% diff %>% max
```

Edit: Should probably point out that those are backticks, not quotation marks.

Comment: This is the best syntax. If you are not familiar with it, it means: `runif(50) %>% diff %>% function(x) { x > 0 } %>% which %>% diff %>% max`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problematic string is parsed to be equivalent to :

```
(runif(50) %>% diff) > (0 %>% which %>% diff %>% max)
```

It returns the same error.

These on the other hand work fine in addition to what has already been proposed:

```
runif(50) %>% {diff(.) > 0} %>% which %>% diff %>% max
(runif(50) %>% diff > 0) %>% which %>% diff %>% max
```